# Write something if no data found in MYSQL table (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

i have simple script to search for things in database. If it not find any result in table it should write down "Neni k dispozici".  My problem is that if i search for something which is not in database it give me back a blanked result. So i try to to write condition if (empty($row)) ... but i never get this result, i just get blanked page again. My second idea was, okey, its maybe not empty. So i try to var_dump($row) and print_r but i get no result anyway. Blanked page...  But if i try to search for something which is in database i get nice var_dump so nothing block this

My code looks like:

```
                 try{
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM axnmrs_calculations WHERE case_id = :case AND country = :country ORDER BY calculation_id DESC LIMIT 1";
                    //$sql = "SELECT * FROM axnmrs_calculations WHERE case_id = :case LIMIT 1";
                    $stmt_calculations = $con->prepare( $sql );
                    $stmt_calculations->bindValue( "case", $this->case, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                    $stmt_calculations->bindValue( "country", $this->country, PDO::PARAM_STR );
                    $stmt_calculations->execute();                   
                    while ($row = $stmt_calculations->fetch()){ 
                    print_r($row);
                    if (empty($row)){
                        echo  "<dt>Údaje ke kalkulaci</dt>";                            
                        echo  "<dd>Neni k dispozici</dd>";} 
                    else{                         
                      $this->calculationid = $row['calculation_id'];

                      echo  "<dt>Cena náhradních dílů</dt>";
                      $spare_parts = floatval($row['spareparts']); // Convert do  FLOAT (kôli number_format funkcii)
                      $spare_parts = number_format($spare_parts, 2, ',', ' ');
                      echo  "<dd>".$spare_parts."</dd>";
                      //echo  "<dd>".$row['spareparts']."</dd>";

                      echo  "<dt>Celkové náklady</dt>";
                      $totalcosts = floatval($row['totalcosts']); // Convert do  FLOAT (kôli number_format funkcii)
                      $totalcosts = number_format($totalcosts, 2, ',', ' ');
                      echo  "<dd>".$totalcosts."</dd>";                          
                      //echo  "<dd>".$row['totalcosts']."</dd>";                           

                      echo  "<dt>Celkový počet hodin práce</dt>";
                      if (empty($row['laborhours'])){
                      echo  "<dd>Neni k dispozici</dd>";} 
                      else                         
                      echo  "<dd>".$row['laborhours']."</dd>";

                      echo  "<dt>Datum vytvoření kalkulace</dt>";
                      if (empty($row['calculationdate'])){
                      echo  "<dd>Neni k dispozici</dd>";} 
                      else                             
                      echo  "<dd>".substr($row['calculationdate'], 0, 10)."</dd>";      // ODSTRANIT 0000

                      echo  "<dt>Lakovací materiál</dt>";
                      if (empty($row['paintmaterial'])){
                      echo  "<dd>Neni k dispozici</dd>";} 
                      else{   
                      $paintmaterial = floatval($row['paintmaterial']); // Convert do  FLOAT (kôli number_format funkcii)
                      $paintmaterial = number_format($paintmaterial, 2, ',', ' ');
                      echo  "<dd>".$paintmaterial."</dd>"; }                           
                      //echo  "<dd>".$row['paintmaterial']."</dd>";

                      echo  "<dt>Měna</dt>";
                      if (empty($row['currency'])){
                      echo  "<dd>Neni k dispozici</dd>";} 
                      else  
                      echo  "<dd>".$row['currency']."</dd>";  
                      }                                                  
                      }

                        }catch(PDOExeption $e){
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                        echo $con->errorInfo();
                        }
```

Can somebody give me advise how can i check if data are in database and if not i write some error message?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can ask how many rows are returned like and add some error handling according to it..

```
if ($statement->execute()) {
    $statement->store_result();
    if ($statement->num_rows >= "1") {
         while ($statement->fetch()) {
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Naruto, thanks for your answer. How ever your code is not working for me. To be more specific, i get 0 result with that.

Comment: If you run the sq in your phpmyadmin, how many results do you get then? could be sql problem..

Comment: 0 result, thats it. There is some problem in PHP imo

Comment: If you get 0 results when you paste your sql in you DB, it mean your sql is the problem, not php..

Comment: i afraid we don't understand each other. I get result for 90% of my search, but sometimes if i search for something i don't have in database i get blanked page. I want that blanked page replace with nice message "We didn't find any result for your search" or something like that.